# For a vector-valued function $F$, never zero with a continuous derivative always parallel to itself, prove that $F(t)=u(t)A$

Tags: calculus, analysis, vector-analysis

I'm having trouble solving the following problem.

A vector-valued function $F$, which is never zero and has a continuous derivative $F'(t)$ for all $t$, is always parallel to its derivative. Prove that there is a constant vector $A$ and a positive real-valued function $u$ such that $F(t)=u(t)A$ for all $t$.

My idea is to use the second fundamental theorem of calculus, $F(x)=F(c)+\int_c^xF'(t)dt$, and the fact that $F\times F'=0$, from the hypotheses that $F'$ is continuous and parallel to $F$. However, I can't get any further from here. I would appreciate any solutions, hints or suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

By hypothesis, there exists a scalar function $\lambda(t)$ such that $F'(t) = \lambda(t) F(t)$. So if $F = (F_1,F_2,\ldots, F_n)$, we have $F_i'(t) = \lambda(t) F_i(t)$ for $i = 1,2,\ldots, n$. Hence $F_i(t) = F_i(0)e^{\int_0^t \lambda(s)\, ds}$ for all $i$. Let $A = (F_1(0), F_2(0),\ldots, F_n(0))$ and $u(t) = e^{\int_0^t \lambda(s)\, ds}$. Then $F(t) = u(t)A$ for all $t$.

Comment: You're welcome. I delete my comment.

Comment: @kobe May I know where did you get the exponential function and why did you set t=0?

Comment: @shinobi20 the ODE $F_i' = \lambda F_i$ are separable, so we may use the separation of variables technique to get the solution displayed in my answer. I don't know what you mean when you ask why I set $t = 0$. :)